# gitignore the all files in directory except one

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want to disable everything in directory `sessions/` except of the file `.htaccess` that disable indexes of the directory, I have this in my `.gitignore`:

```
sessions/*
```

but this also ignore `.htaccess` file that inside sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add exceptions with exclamation mark:

```
sessions/*
!sessions/.htaccess
```